# Prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\int_0^1f^n(x)\ln(x+a)dx}{\int_0^1f^n(x)dx}=\ln a$.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $f$ be a function which definites on $\mathbb{R}$ and  has a third derivative, such that
$$f'(0)=0,f''(0)=-2,f'''(0)>0,f'(1)=1,f''(1)=4,f'''(1)>0.$$
and for any $x\in (0,1)$, $0<f(x)<f(0)=f(1)=1$. If $a>1$, then prove that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\int_0^1f^n(x)\ln(x+a)dx}{\int_0^1f^n(x)dx}=\ln a.$$

In this problem $f$ requires so many conditions. Maybe we can choose a simple function $f$ to have a try, such as $f(x)=1-x^2+x^3$, but I can't figure it out. In adition, I wonder why $a>1$?It seems that we can try to write
$\ln (x+a)=\ln a+\ln (1+\frac{x}{a})$ and then expand $\ln(1+\frac{x}{a})$at $0$, and try to prove that for any $k\in \mathbb{N}$,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\int_0^1f^n(x)x^kdx}{\int_0^1f^n(x)dx}=0.$$

Comment: Is $f^n(x) =( f(x))^n$?

Comment: Yes!It's $(f(x))^n$,not $f(x^n)$